# How to control chance of won a prize from an array

Tags: php, arrays

Imagine we have an array like below sample array and we want to get a random prize from it.

But, we want control chance of win for each prize which is mean we want control which one of our prizes have higher or lower chance for win.

```php
<?php 

$prizes = [
    ["title" => "1st Prize", "chance" => "10"],
    ["title" => "2nd Prize", "chance" => "15"],
    ["title" => "3rd Prize", "chance" => "50"],
    ["title" => "4th Prize", "chance" => "35"],
    ["title" => "5th Prize", "chance" => "75"],
    ["title" => "6th Prize", "chance" => "35"],
    ["title" => "7th Prize", "chance" => "55"],
    ["title" => "8th Prize", "chance" => "99"],
    ["title" => "9th Prize", "chance" => "11"],
];

?>
```

Comment: Please show the code you've written so far to attempt to raise or lower the chance of winning a prize.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, those chances add up to more than 100%. Is it possible to win multiple prizes at once?

The way I would do this is to just pick a random number between 1 and 100, e.g.

`$rng = rand(1,100);`.
Then compare the result against all the `chance` fields of the array. If the random number was equal to or less than the `chance` for a certain prize, then the user wins that prize.

Answer (score 0):

One of of doing it is to sum all the chances, and then randomize a number that large are see where it "hits":

```
// Sum the chances
$totalChances = 0;
foreach ($prizes as $prize) {
    $totalChances += $prize['chance'];
}

// Randomize a number:
$rand = rand(0, $totalChances);

// Pick a prize
$currPize = '';
$currChance = 0;
$i = 0;
do {
    $currChance += $prizes[i]['chance'];
    $i++;
} while ($currChance < $prizes[i]['chance']);
```